# Trying to make a .db file with flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I was following a tutorial on youtube. At 20:00 they ask to create .db file. They go to a python shell and type:

```
from main import db
db.create_all()
```

When I try importing db it comes up with an error. The error says that there is no module called flask, but I have already installed flask and imported it. How do I get it to create the .db file?

This is the error:
[image: error]

This in the code:
[image: code]

The tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RJmh_OqeA&t=1206s

Comment: You have to install flask too

Comment: You had probably forgotten to activate a virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

First, check if it's really installed by typing this, make sure you're in the same directory:

```
pip list
```

this should list the downloaded dependencies. If Flask isn't there then it's not probably installed, this problem is not specified in Flask Documentation but I've seen it many times, try using pip3 instead of pip

```
pip3 install flask
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes from your environment ^^
You should set your environment by using this command: `source env/bin/activate`

Answer (score -1):

your problem is that you don't have flask installed

[image]

execute

```
pip install flask
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

> I recommend that you use requirement.txt
> Blockquote

Example:

[image]

execute:
pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: but OP says he already installed it

Comment: if you see the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module 'flask". It hasn't been installed